# jQuery animated menu dropdowns that occupy full width of container

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate

I'm trying to edit the following jQuery animated menu so that the width of the subtext div is absolute 600px instead of being relative to the width of the parent menu list item.

[Click here for the code](http://tinyurl.com/ckgkhjf)

I tried adding absolute position to the subtext class but it didn't work.

This is what I'm trying to get when I hover the "About" menu item for example.

[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: post your code ... it's easier to guess if we can take a look at it, a prinscreen isn't enough

Comment: Try with adding the property "position:relative" to the li tag in CSS and then your absolute to your p tags.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried that but it didn't work!

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/sGZh3/) of the page.

Comment: Depending on whether there is some sort of responsive design or a seperate mobile page you could consider to open the menu also by click. Especially if there are important navigation points inside the box. Otherwise it's impossible to navigate trough your page with touch devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Demo using jQuery animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/x7UPk/1/)
- [Demo using CSS transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/JLkJM/3/)   (not animated in IE9 and earlier)

Below are some of the styles that were the most important:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;     /* Get rid of bullets on li tags */
    position: relative;   /* Use relative position here, but not on li tags */
}
li {
    /* position: relative; */   /* Remove this style, to make all dropdown
                                   divs appear at the same location */
}
a {
    outline: none;   /* Get rid of outline on links */
}
.subtext {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
li:hover .subtext {
    z-index: 2;   /* Make sure the active menu dropdown is on top */
}
/* Apply background color to both the li tags and the dropdown divs */
.green,  .green  .subtext { background-color: #6AA63B; }
.yellow, .yellow .subtext { background-color: #FBC700; }
.red,    .red    .subtext { background-color: #D52100; }
.purple, .purple .subtext { background-color: #5122B4; }
.blue,   .blue   .subtext { background-color: #0292C0; }
```

The version with CSS transitions adds the following styles:

```
.subtext {
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
       -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
            transition: height 0.6s;
}
li:hover .subtext {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Both demos use the same HTML, and most of the same CSS. Neither version required editing the existing HTML. The version with CSS transitions requires no jQuery.

Comment: That's perfect, Matt. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of achieving this:

Remove `position: relative;` from li, add `display: none;` and `height:0;` to .subtext

Then modify the javascript code as such:

```
//When mouse rolls over
$("li").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.subtext').hide(); // remove this for a fancier effect
    $(this).find('.subtext').css({backgroundColor: $(this).css('backgroundColor')})
    $(this).find('.subtext').stop().animate({height:'250px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: ''}).show()
});

//When mouse is removed
$("li").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.subtext').stop().animate({height:'0px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: ''}, function() {$(this).find('.subtext').hide()})
});
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vuRLF/)